# removing the items dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the dynamically created elements with jquery, so far i am not successful because every time i click the x button, after 2 or 3 clicks, it removes all elements while i want to delete only the element it is clicked

```
<div class="modal"><label for=""></label><input data-placement="bottom" type="text" name="client_status_1" id="client_status_1"><input type="button" id="btRemove" rel="client_status_1" value="X" class="sectionBtn bt"></div>

<div class="modal"><label for=""></label><input data-placement="bottom" type="text" name="client_status_2" id="client_status_2"><input type="button" id="btRemove" rel="client_status_2" value="X" class="sectionBtn bt"></div>

<div class="modal"><label for=""></label><input data-placement="bottom" type="text" name="client_status_3" id="client_status_3"><input type="button" id="btRemove" rel="client_status_3" value="X" class="sectionBtn bt"></div>

<div class="modal"><label for=""></label><input data-placement="bottom" type="text" name="client_status_4" id="client_status_4"><input type="button" id="btRemove" rel="client_status_4" value="X" class="sectionBtn bt"></div>
```

here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click','#btRemove', function() {
    var btnRemovalItem = $(this).attr('rel').split('_')[2];  
    iCnt = btnRemovalItem;
    if (iCnt != 0) { 
        $('#bt' + iCnt).remove(); 
        iCnt = iCnt - 1; 
    }
    if (iCnt == 0) { 
        $(container).empty(); 
        $(container).remove(); 
        $('#btAdd').removeAttr('disabled'); 
        $('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt')
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `container`? Also, `btnRemovalItem` is a string, not an integer.

Comment: You can not have multiple elements with the same id

Comment: First of all, the `id` field should be unique across a document, so any id should be assigned to no more than one element.
Second, I suggest using $("#btRemove").parents(".modal") to find the `.modal` the button is placed within. See the docs: https://api.jquery.com/parents/ .

Comment: There is some ambiguity in your question: what is `container`? What are you trying to do to it? What do you want to remove? The input element, or the entire modal element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first major problem with your markup is that you are using the same ID for multiple elements. **IDs must be unique in the document** and cannot be reused, therefore I suggest you use `btRemove` as a class instead.

If you want to remove the input, can you simply not traverse up the document tree and remove the `.model` parent using `.closest()`?

p/s: I am unable to understand your intention of using the `container` variable since it is not defined in your script, so you might want to update your question about what exactly you are trying to do by (1) contining the number of containers and (2) what do you want to be removed—the parent element, or just the preceeding input element.

```js
$(document).on('click','.btRemove', function() {
    $(this).closest('.modal').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal"><label for=""></label><input data-placement="bottom" type="text" name="client_status_1" id="client_status_1"><input type="button" rel="client_status_1" value="X" class="btRemove sectionBtn bt"></div>

<div class="modal"><label for=""></label><input data-placement="bottom" type="text" name="client_status_2" id="client_status_2"><input type="button" rel="client_status_2" value="X" class="btRemove sectionBtn bt"></div>

<div class="modal"><label for=""></label><input data-placement="bottom" type="text" name="client_status_3" id="client_status_3"><input type="button" rel="client_status_3" value="X" class="btRemove sectionBtn bt"></div>

<div class="modal"><label for=""></label><input data-placement="bottom" type="text" name="client_status_4" id="client_status_4"><input type="button" rel="client_status_4" value="X" class="btRemove sectionBtn bt"></div>
```